# how to get magento2 base url for backend?

Tags: magento2, admin, controllers, base-url

I want replacement of following in Magento 2

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("module_name/controller_name/action_name/");
```

Comment: In magento 1.,`Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("module_name/controller_name/action_name/")` give  admin section url not base url.I guess that you want **url of  admin**

Answer (score 7):

Inside controller you can get this by following way

```
$this->getUrl($route, $params)
```

Another way

Create **\Magento\Backend\Helper\Data** object by objectManager.

```
$this->_helper->getUrl($route, $params)
```

**$this->_helper** is **Magento\Backend\Helper\Data**

Comment: First solution in working quite well.
Thanks